# Using Euler's formula to prove a theorem about number of edges on a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Consider a polyhedron with at least five faces such that
exactly three edges emerge from each of its vertices.

Prove the polygon has a face with at least 4 edges.

This was asked in the $2002$ Putnam and the solutions mention that it is possible to use Euler's formula to prove. How do I do it?

Solutions: (See B2) http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2002s.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's formula says $f-e+v=2$.  Suppose $f\geq 5$ and each vertex has exactly $3$ incident edges.  The latter fact means $3v=2e$ since each edge is incident to two vertices as well, hence $v-e=\frac{2}{3}e-e=-\frac{1}{3}e$, so Euler's formula reduces to $f-\frac{1}{3}e=2$.

Suppose to the contrary that every face has at most $3$ edges, and thus exactly $3$ since a polyhedron does not have bigons.  Then $3f=2e$ since every face has $3$ edges and every edge has $2$ incident faces. Hence $\frac{3}{2}f=e$, so $2=f-\frac{1}{3}e=\frac{1}{2}f$.  Thus $f=4$, contradicting the fact the polyhedron has at least $5$ faces.

Comment: Thank you for the solution